# Are all surjections continuous functions?

Tags: functions, continuity

I am reading [Wikipedia page about affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), and have not read it English version, but in Russian, it written, that "continuity follows from the definition in a not quite trivial way".

Do I understand correctly, that affine transformations are continuous, because they are a bijection?
Every bijection function is continuous, and not every injection or surject is continuous?

---

My understanding

A function is continuous, as I understand, if each $X$ has $Y$. Bijection satisfies this requirement: each Y has one and only one $X$, hence each $X$ has $Y$.

I actually, can't currently mathematically prove, that if each $Y$ has one and only $X$, then each $X$ has $Y$, but it obviously means, that for infinite amount of $Y$ should exist infinite amount of unique $X$.

Comment: I think continuity is nothing to do with injection, surjection or bijection, continuity is a special property of a mapping whereas injection, surjection, bijection are different classifications of mapping

Comment: No, they are continuous because we are in finite dimensions. In infinite dimensional affine space, affine transformations don't need to be continuous. It certainly has nothing to do with being bijective or surjective.

Comment: @DeeponjitBose, I explained why do I think it is related in question update

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I almost understand what Affine transformations are, however I do not clearly understand what does continuity mean in this case. Can You explain? Maybe it means that transformation could be applied through all space, i.e. any point can be transformed?

Comment: "A function is continuous, as I understand, if each X has Y."  No, this is nothing like the definition of continuous.

Comment: @JBL, prove that, please

Comment: In this case, all affine transformations $T$ in finite dimensions have a $C>0$ such that for all points $x,y,$ $$d(Tx,Ty)\leq C\cdot d(x,y),$$ where $d$ is the distance function. This is a strong form of continuity. Continuity means, roughly, that if $x$ and $y$ are close, then $Tx$ and $Ty$ will be close.

Comment: You are demanding proof that you are wrong about a definition? @Stdugnd4ikbd You have a complete misunderstanding about continuity. The internet is full of definitions of it. Surjective, bijective, injective have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I rather asking, not demanding. I am a bit confused, about Your $T$ objects, maybe You meant $X_t,Y_t$ instead, i.e. transformed $x$ and $y$? Otherwise, I do not understand how You compare transformation, i.e. a map, and a scalar. And how You getting distance between transformations also

Comment: That's a notation thing. I used $x$ and $y$ for full points, which you might write as $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n).$ But an important thing about affine spaces is that such "coordinate" representations are not fundamental. It is better to think in terms of full points rather than as something with coordinates.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, yeah, I understand that $x$ and $y$ stands for point, and are kinda vector values (because consists of multiple values), but I did not get about notation. You $Tx$ is transformed $x$, i.e. the result of transformation of given $x$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, can You please, at least describe what $C$ is in Your formula?